How to configure a Zebra TC21 Datawedge profile programatically in an Android Kotlin app?
I am developing an Android inventory app in Kotlin for Zebra TC21 devices, and I would like to configure a Datawedge profile programmatically. I need to scan qr codes with the integrated scanner, and RFID tags with a Zebra RFD4031. I would like the scanned data to be transmitted by "Intent output" with Broadcast mode. I also want the "key output" to be disabled.
I tried with this code:
class DatawedgeConfig {
    val baseConfig = createBaseConfig()

    fun initialize(context: Context) {
        try {
            createProfile(context)
            configureProfile(context)
            configureInput(context)
            configureOutput(context)
            Log.d("DatawedgeConfig", "DataWedge initialized successfully")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("DatawedgeConfig", "Error initializing DataWedge", e)
        }
    }

    private fun createBaseConfig(): Bundle {
        return Bundle().apply {
            putString("PROFILE_NAME", DATAWEDGE_PROFILE_NAME)
            putString("PROFILE_ENABLED", "true")
            putString("CONFIG_MODE", "UPDATE")
        }
    }

    fun createProfile(context: Context) {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION"
        intent.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.CREATE_PROFILE", DATAWEDGE_PROFILE_NAME)
        try {
            context.sendBroadcast(intent)
            Log.d("DatawedgeConfig", "Profile created successfully")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("DatawedgeConfig", "Error creating profile", e)
        }
    }

    fun configureProfile(context: Context) {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION"
        intent.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG", Bundle().apply {
            baseConfig.putParcelableArray("APP_LIST", arrayOf(Bundle().apply {
                putString("PACKAGE_NAME", context.packageName)
                putStringArray("ACTIVITY_LIST", arrayOf("*"))
            }))
        })

        Log.d("DataWedgeConfig", "Configuring profile: $baseConfig")

        try {
            context.sendBroadcast(intent)
            Log.d("DatawedgeConfig", "Profile configured successfully (PACKAGE_NAME : ${context.packageName})")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("DatawedgeConfig", "Error configuring profile", e)
        }
    }

    fun configureInput(context: Context) {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION"
        intent.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG", Bundle().apply {
            baseConfig.putParcelableArray("PLUGIN_CONFIG", arrayOf(Bundle().apply {
                putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "BARCODE")
                putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
                putBundle("PARAM_LIST", Bundle().apply {
                    putString("scanner_selection", "auto")
                    putString("decoder_rfid", "true")
                    putString("decoder_qr_code", "true")
                })
            }))
        })
        try {
            context.sendBroadcast(intent)
            Log.d("DatawedgeConfig", "Input configured successfully")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("DatawedgeConfig", "Error configuring input", e)
        }
    }

    fun configureOutput(context: Context) {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION"
        intent.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG", Bundle().apply {
            baseConfig.putParcelableArray("PLUGIN_CONFIG", arrayOf(Bundle().apply {
                putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "INTENT")
                putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
                putBundle("PARAM_LIST", Bundle().apply {
                    putString("intent_output_enabled", "true")
                    putString("intent_action", DATAWEDGE_ACTION)
                    putString("intent_delivery", "2")
                })
            }))
        })
        try {
            context.sendBroadcast(intent)
            Log.d("DatawedgeConfig", "Output configured successfully")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("DatawedgeConfig", "Error configuring output", e)
        }
    }
}

The profile is actually created if it doesn't exist, but none of the options in the "SET_CONFIG" bundle is apllied. So, my app isn't associated with the created profile, and the intent output isn't neither enabled nor configured with the given values.
I don't understand why.

I've finally found a solution. I share it for those who'd be interested:
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class DWConfig @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
) {
    val setConfigBundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString("PROFILE_NAME", DATAWEDGE_PROFILE_NAME)
        putString("PROFILE_ENABLED", "true")
        putString("CONFIG_MODE", "CREATE_IF_NOT_EXIST")
    }

    val appConfig = Bundle().apply {
        putString("PACKAGE_NAME", context.packageName)
        putStringArray(
            "ACTIVITY_LIST", arrayOf(
                "${context.packageName}.MainActivity",
            )
        )
    }

    val barcodeParamList = Bundle().apply {
        putString("scanner_input_enabled", "true")
        putString("scanner_selection", "auto")
        putString("charset_name", "ISO-8859-1")
        putString("auto_charset_preferred_order", "UTF-8;GB2312")
        putString("auto_charset_failure_option", "UTF-8")
        putString("volume_slider_type", "3")
    }

    val barcodeConfigBundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "BARCODE")
        putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
    }

    val intentParamList = Bundle().apply {
        putString("intent_output_enabled", "true")
        putString("intent_action", DATAWEDGE_INTENT_ACTION)
        putString("intent_delivery", "2")
    }

    val intentConfigBundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "INTENT")
        putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
    }

    val rfidParamList = Bundle().apply {
        putString("rfid_input_enabled", "true")
        putString("rfid_beeper_enable", "false")
        putString("rfid_led_enable", "true")
        putString("rfid_antenna_transmit_power", "30")
        putString("rfid_memory_bank", "3")
        putString("rfid_session", "1")
        putString("rfid_trigger_mode", "0")
        putString("rfid_filter_duplicate_tags", "true")
        putString("rfid_hardware_trigger_enabled", "true")
        putString("rfid_tag_read_duration", "250")
    }

    val rfidConfigBundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "RFID")
        putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
    }

    val keystrokeParamList = Bundle().apply {
        putString("keystroke_output_enabled", "false")
    }

    val keystrokeConfigBundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "KEYSTROKE")
        putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
    }

    private fun setAppList() {
        setConfigBundle.putParcelableArray(
            "APP_LIST", arrayOf(
                appConfig
            )
        )
    }
    
    private fun setPluginConfig() {
        setConfigBundle.remove("PLUGIN_CONFIG")
        barcodeConfigBundle.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", barcodeParamList)
        intentConfigBundle.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", intentParamList)
        rfidConfigBundle.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", rfidParamList)
        keystrokeConfigBundle.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", keystrokeParamList)

        setConfigBundle.putParcelableArrayList(
            "PLUGIN_CONFIG", arrayListOf(
                barcodeConfigBundle,
                intentConfigBundle,
                rfidConfigBundle,
                keystrokeConfigBundle
            )
        )
    }

    private fun sendConfig() {
        val intent = Intent().apply {
            action = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION"
            putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG", setConfigBundle)
        }

        context.sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    fun initialize() : Boolean {
        try {
            
            setAppList()
            setPluginConfig()
            sendConfig()
            return true
            
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            
            Log.e("DWConfig", "Error initializing DataWedge", e)
            return false
            
        }
    }
}

I call initialize() method during the launch of my app:
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dwConfig: DWConfig
) : ViewModel() {

    fun initializeDataWedge(): Boolean {
        return dwConfig.initialize()
    }

    ...

}

@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication : Application() {
    @Composable
    fun App(activity: MainActivity, mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {

            val dataWedgeJob = async { mainViewModel.initializeDataWedge() }
            
            ...

            dataWedgeJob.await()

            ...
}

I found most of the informations that I needed here (unfortunately, all the examples are written in Java) :
https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/13-0/guide/api/setconfig/
Almost all the parameters that you can configure in the Datawedge App are referenced here with their ids and their possible values that you can set programmatically.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
